# how to make this http://www.example.com/demo To http://www.example.com

Tags: wordpress

I want to move website from http://www.example.com/demo .... to http://www.example.com

How it possible without changing anything means pages-posts-images

Comment: hi ,
i have used custom menu plugin and arranged some widgets for separate pages , i want those all too .....but i am not getting can u please help me in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed Wordpress at `http://www.example.com/demo` and now want to access it at `http://www.example.com` , this [article from the Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) will help you.
You will be done in a couple of steps.

Comment: Thank You so much ..... i have done successfully

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect /demo http://www.example.com
```

And add this to your `index.php` file in your top directory:

```
 <?php
 include '/demo';
 ?>
```

Comment: Its a wordpress Website so can anyone suggest me the easiest way and safest one....