# Add django-material app/view at root/home (http://www.example.com/)

Tags: django

I try to understand how it is possible to do the same as on http://demo.viewflow.io with the view 'Introduction'.

How I can integrate a ?app or view? on root/home of my domain in the menu of the django-material layout? see http://www.schneewind.ch/stackoverflow/demo.viewflow.io.png

I tried different ways, but not yet found the right one. I thing I didn't understand something right (perhaps on django-layer?)

-> Not the same but similar idea for worldpress: [how to make this http://www.example.com/demo To http://www.example.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071408/how-to-make-this-http-www-example-com-demo-to-http-www-example-com)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample demo module

```
class Demo(ModuleMixin):
    """
    Home page module
    """
    order = 1
    label = 'Introduction'
    icon = '<i class="material-icons">account_balance</i>'

    @property
    def urls(self):
        return frontend.ModuleURLResolver(
            '^', [url('^$', IndexView.as_view(), name="index")],
            module=self, app_name='demo', namespace='demo')

    def index_url(self):
        return '/'

    def installed(self):
        return True
```